How to read from a full named pipe in C to check how many bytes need to be read before writing again?
I have an assignment to:
a) check the capacity of a named pipe (FIFO)
b) check how many bytes I need to read from a full pipe before writing again.
My code successfully writes into the pipe until it is full and says that 65536 bytes is its capacity, yet then reading fails (the value checked by the if condition is -1), and for reasons unknown to me it manages to write into a full pipe without reading anything. The error code for the read fail is 'Resource temporarily unavailable'. Below is my code with the debugging prints removed for clarity. The output of the code is 'Write successful after reading 0 bytes'.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int l = 0;
    int stream;
    char* fifo = "/tmp/fifo";
    mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
    char test = 255;
    int p = fork();
    char readtest;

    if (p > 0) { //rodzic
        wait(NULL);
        stream = open(fifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
        while (1) {
            if (read(stream, &readtest, 1) == 1) {
                l++;
                printf("Read byte %d, attempting write", l);
            }
            if (write(stream, &test, 1) == 1) {
                printf("Write successful after reading %d bytes\n", l);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } else if (p == 0) { //dziecko
        stream = open(fifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
        while (write(stream, &test, 1) == 1 ) {
            l++;
            //printf("b%d\n", l);
        }
        close(stream);
        printf("Wrote %d bytes, pipe full\n", l);
        _Exit(0);
    }


Both processes are writing to the pipe at the same time. So why do you think only the bytes in the child process represent the capacity? And the parent process is consuming at the same time.

If you want to check the pipe's capacity, don't read from it while writing. Just write to it until you get an EWOULDBLOCK error.

Aside: mixing calls to mkfifo() and fork() in with your variable declarations is really horrible and confusing.

Once you get into that state, you can do alternate reading and writing to see when you can write again.

@Barmar Am I misunderstanding or did you miss the wait() call at the beginning of the parent process? The parent waits until the child finishes writing to the pipe and cannot write no more, then terminates. Only then the parent process tries reading.

At any time, if the pipe/FIFO has space for N bytes, you can write N bytes.  Reading one byte from the full FIFO means you can write one byte.  If you read multiple bytes (N of them) before anything is written, then you can write N bytes.  It really isn't clear what the second half of the assignment is supposed to show.

Yes, I didn't realize that was what's going on there. So you don't really need two processes, you can just put the child process's loop in place of wait(NULL).

@JonathanLeffler The assumption seems to be that reading one byte won't actually make the pipe writable immediately, perhaps because the buffer is in chunks. So you have to read N bytes before you can start writing again.

Barmar, thank you very much, I don't know why but it worked.
@JonathanLeffler A week ago I had a similar assignment for checking normal pipe parameters, basically the same thing but calling pipe() instead of mkfifo(). I did not let me write until after reading 4096 bytes. Exactly the same thing happens here after applying Barmar's suggestion, write fails until 4096 bytes are read.

@Barmar: that's an assumption that, if true, would make some sense of the exercise.  I don't think the assumption is true — a single byte read leaves enough room for a single byte to be written.

You need to check the values you are reading.  Have the parent write a different value than the child.  Continue the loop a bit.  (ie, have the parent write a single byte and then read a byte.)  See if the value you get came from the parent or from the child.  You might be surprised.

@JonathanLeffler When running the program, it should prove it one way or the other.

Use unix sockets (man 7 unix or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html ) instead of pipes for bidirectional connections. The manual pages also contain an implementation example.

In this case, the parent and child are using different pipes.  Normally (not non-blocking), when you open a fifo for writing the open will not return until some other process opens the same fifo for reading.  At that point, the 2 processes are sharing a pipe.  Since your child is opening the fifo non-blocking, it does not wait for a reader.  When the child closes the pipe, all the data that it wrote vanishes into the ether.  The parent subsequently opens the fifo and gets a different pipe that has never been written to.
To get around this, you need to have the parent open the fifo before the child closes it.

Also relevant: opening in O_RDWR mode succeeds immediately, since that process is both reader and writer.

Or you get around it by not using multiple processes, as I suggested above in comments.

Note that I don't know if this behavior is standard.  It is what I am observing on my extraordinarily ancient Mac.  I can see other platforms implementing different behavior.  Would be curious to know if this is standardized.

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html: "Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both
in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior
undefined."
